# Encoding php array in json is unterminated

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a strange problem with json_encode applying on a returned array from mysql. Is not terminated and it looks like

```
$products = json_encode($products);  

[{"prod_name":"Intel Xeon E5-2430 v2 Processor Option for ThinkServer RD340\/RD44\
```

The echoed is the result of my restAPI

I never met this issue how to debug?
On another server works fine.

On running server I have

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 28 2014 23:19:50) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with XCache v1.3.2, Copyright (c) 2005-2011, by mOo
```

running on ISPConfig

Comment: Did you copy-paste the JSON directly from the browser window?

Comment: is the returned from restAPI

Comment: That string is escaped as well. If this is literally what is returned, then the early termination isn't your only problem.

Comment: I found that the double escaping comes from double json encoding but even after fixing this the literally is the same. Unterminated